# Arquillian Test

Tags: automated-tests, jboss-arquillian

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: test.war
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:83)

...

at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)Caused by: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"test.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name enumBean resolves to beans:-Managed Bean [class br.mil.eb.cds.sil.comum.interfaces.EnumBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],- Managed Bean [class br.mil.eb.cds.sil.comum.interfaces.EnumBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]"}}
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getActionResult(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:134)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.getResultFromNode(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:123)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:85)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.impl.ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.get(ServerDeploymentPlanResultFuture.java:42)
at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.standalone.ServerDeploymentHelper.deploy(ServerDeploymentHelper.java:55)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:77)
... 88 more
```

I am using arquillian platform for automated-tests.

I am using WildFly 8.2 Final is released!

Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with CDI. Given that the name for the ambiguous beans looks the same, I am wondering whether there are also class loader problems. I suggest you post your test code as well.

Comment: Please provide more information about your deployment.  Obviously the deployment is failing. You need to figure out why.

Comment: beans:-Managed Bean [class br.mil.eb.cds.sil.comum.interfaces.EnumBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],- Managed Bean [class br.mil.eb.cds.sil.comum.interfaces.EnumBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]"}}" The ejroe
=======>
The error message has given your enough info.

If possible please paste your EnumBean code and esp your @Deployment method code in your tests.